# Rails 3 runner not detecting JSON gem?

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, runner

I'm trying to create **Ruby** script to run with my **Rails 3** environment.

However, whenever I run this rubyscript with **Rails Runner**, I get this error:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

@payload = {
"message" => "helloworld",
"station" => {"id"=>12345}
}.to_json

puts @payload
```

**ERROR:**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:198:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `new_constants_in'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:198:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `require'
 from createflags.rb:2
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `eval'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:47
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:39
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6
```

Can someone please tell me what I can do to fix this?

Comment: gem list correctly shows: json (1.4.6, 1.4.3) &
json_pure (1.4.6, 1.4.3). This script runs fine with "ruby scriptName.rb", but not with "rails runner script.rb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally familiar with the internals of Bundler, but it may be that it doesn't allow `require`ing other gems not in the Gemfile. Maybe adding `gem 'json'` would take care of this.

Of course, ActiveSupport has its own JSON module, so there should be no need to pull in another gem.

Answer (score 0):

remove require "json" and then try. I believe ActiveSupport already has to_json in built.